# Angular 2 keeps style from one component to the next

Tags: css, angular

I got a small problem, I define my components like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'documents',
    styleUrls: ['./documents.scss', '../../../../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css', '../../../../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css', '../../../../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'],
    templateUrl: './documents.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    providers:[

    ],
})
```

Inside my css files I have sometimes the same name for classes e.g.

```
//CSS 1 
.boxHeader {
  position: absolute
  background-color: red;
}
//CSS 2
.boxHeader {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

So if I open the components directly its working like excepted, only css1 or css2 gets loaded. The problem is if the user navigates between them, angular keeps the css files of the previous one. The result if I navigate from 1 to 2 is this:

```
//CSS 2
.boxHeader {
  position: absolute; //This one gets inserted from CSS1
  background-color: blue; //This one gets overwritten
}
```

Is there a way to tell `ngOnDestroy()` to delete all style references ?

EDIT This way I bound it:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/sass/roboto-fontface.scss",
        "../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
        "../node_modules/ionicons/scss/ionicons.scss",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
        "../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
        "../node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css",
        "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css",
        "../node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css",
        "../node_modules/ng2-slim-loading-bar/style.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css", //new
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css", //new
        "app/theme/theme.scss",
        "styles.scss"
      ],
```

The comments are not inside, this little Error it returns now:

```
Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.
```

Comment: @torazaburo ViewEncapsulation.None I inserted cause otherwise I got problems loading primeng. If I define the styles within cli how do I define which components they affect ?

Comment: @torazaburo Yes for primeng, but my problem is with the component bounded css files.

Comment: @torazaburo yes with styleUrls I bound it to the component, my problem is if I navigate trough my site the loaded css files affect other components too.

Comment: @Doomenik Remove ViewEncapsulation.None as it will leak your css to other components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't insert your css links inside your styleUrls, it should only include css for that specific components only. From your code it should only contain the documents.scss.

For your primeng and font awesome styles, insert it in your index.html or you can insert it in your angular-cli.json

I.e

```
 "styles": [
     "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css", 
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css", 
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      ],
```

Also, remove the  ViewEncapsulation.None as it will leak your css to other components, unless if that is what you want.

**Update 1**

If you are getting this error

```
Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.
```

The error is how you define your styleUrl. Try this

```
styleUrls: ['./documents.scss']
```

instead of just a string.

Comment: Tried it this way, problem is now:  Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings. Even after reverting it I have now this little nasty error

Comment: @Doomenik Have you tried putting the styles in your index.html?

Comment: First ty, I think the removing of encapsulation could do the trick. I edited the way I inserted it in my question. I would prefer to not define it inside my index.html.

Comment: @Doomenik just wondering, putting your styles in your angular-cli.json still not working?

Comment: No thats why I cant try if removing ViewEncapsulation.None would work ^^

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: I got it, I had the definition already like in your updated answer, the problem was other components also loaded primeng. After removing it from every component it works now ty.

Comment: @torazaburo I know, but this was not the only thing and you didn´t explained why.